# Traefik's replacepath gives 2 different results with the same config

Tags: docker, docker-compose, traefik

When using **replacepath** in Traefik I get 2 different results for very similarly configured services, which is quite... frustrating.

**Expected behaviour**:

When I open **https://hostname/nginx2**:

- the url in browser remains unchanged
- page opens with expected content (nginx error page for non-existing content)

**Unexpected behaviour**:

When I open **https://hostname/pihole**:

- the browser is redirected to https://hostname/admin (was expecting the url to remain unchanged)
- Traefik's [404 page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ro2To.png) opens (was expecting to see a page served by pihole)

Here's the relevant part of my docker-compose.yml. The only difference in labels is the service name, yet the services behave differently. What's going on here?

```
  pihole:
    container_name: pihole
    image: pihole/pihole:latest
    ports:
      - "53:53/tcp"
      - "53:53/udp"
    environment:
      TZ: 'Europe/Warsaw'
      DNS1: 127.0.0.1
      DNS2: 9.9.9.9
    volumes:
      - './etc-pihole:/etc/pihole'
      - './etc-dnsmasq.d:/etc/dnsmasq.d'
      - '/etc/resolv.conf:/etc/resolv.conf'
    restart: unless-stopped
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.pihole.middlewares=pihole"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.pihole.replacepath.path=/admin"
      - "traefik.http.routers.pihole.entrypoints=web,websecure"
      - "traefik.http.routers.pihole.rule=Path(`/pihole`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.pihole.tls=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.pihole.tls.certresolver=production"
      - "traefik.http.services.pihole.loadbalancer.server.port=80"
      - "traefik.port=80"

  nginx2:
    image: nginx:latest
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.nginx2.middlewares=nginx2"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.nginx2.replacepath.path=/admin"
      - "traefik.http.routers.nginx2.entrypoints=web,websecure"
      - "traefik.http.routers.nginx2.rule=Path(`/nginx2`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.nginx2.tls=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.nginx2.tls.certresolver=production"
      - "traefik.http.services.nginx2.loadbalancer.server.port=80"
      - "traefik.port=80"
```